# Redirecting input value to search on google with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How would I take an input value and redirect it as a search on google?
It's currently redirecting to google, with the search value string showing in the url and the google input field, but it dosn't fire off the search until I press enter.

This is what I've come up with, is there another way this is supose to be done?

```
onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let searchValue = this.refs.input.value;
    searchValue = searchValue.replace(/\s+/g, '+');
    window.location.replace(`http://google.com/?q=${searchValue}`);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not taking the user to the correct page. To execute the search on behalf of the user, use:

```
window.location.replace(`https://www.google.com/search?q=${searchValue}`);
```

The `/search` page is where the actual search is executed from. In addition, Google supports secure browsing (i.e. `https`). As an added bonus, I've modified your url example to support this extra layer of security.